# VBA creates XML but need CSV instead

Tags: xml, vba, soap

I have this VBA script that will call a webservice and save the data into an XML file. Instead of XML, how can I modify the script to save the data as a CSV file instead?

```
Sub Call_Pipeline_Macros()

    Dim sURL As String
    Dim sEnv As String
    Dim xmlhtp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim xmlDoc As New DOMDocument
    sURL = "http://service.leads360.com/ClientService.asmx"

    sEnv = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">"
    sEnv = sEnv & "  <soap:Body>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "    <GetReportResults xmlns=""https://service.leads360.com"">"
    sEnv = sEnv & "      <username>vtorralbes@globalhealtheducation.com</username>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "      <password>XXXXX</password>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "      <reportId>565</reportId>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "    </GetReportResults>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "  </soap:Body>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "</soap:Envelope>"

    With xmlhtp
        .Open "post", sURL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Host", "service.leads360.com"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
        .setRequestHeader "soapAction", "https://service.leads360.com/GetReportResults"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept-encoding", "zip"
        .send sEnv
        xmlDoc.LoadXML .responseText
        xmlDoc.Save "X:\share\Reporting Database\XML Files" & "\565_pipeline_report.xml"

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If the data is returned as XML then you'd have to convert that content to a comma-separated format and save that to file. Hard to be more specific without seeing the layout of the XML.

Comment: Thanks Tim...that's my question. Instead of the data returning as XML, can I just have it return and save as CSV?

Comment: That is controlled by the web service - if it only supports returning data as xml then you're stuck with that.

Comment: Indeed, why do you want to save it as csv? In theory it will be the same data in a text file with a format that you might not be able to use for the purpose you need. You can reference a library (MSXML) and manipulate XML files through VBA depending on the layout of the XML.

Comment: Show us the XML and what your desired output would look like. Otherwise it's almost impossible to help.

Answer (score 0):

An example of the reply can be found here: http://service.leads360.com/Documentation/Examples/Client/GetReportResults.templateValues.txt

It doesn't look like the webservice can return anything else than soap xml. As mentioned, you will have to loop through the XML-string already loaded in `xmlDoc` and output values as needed to create one CSV-string per record, separated by vbCrLf (newline) and then save as text-file.